# Faster VBA Vlookup

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

In Tab "FISV 03-05" I have values in column C.  I want to lookup this same value in Column C of tab "PF Outstandings" and return the value of Column D into the Column D of the "FISV 03-05" tab.  It has to be an exact match and I have over 250K rows of data to look up values on (it takes over 20 minutes with a vlookup formula in Excel)

Is there anyway to make this vlookup in VBA so it takes less time?  Each value in Column C and In Column D are unique

```
FISV 03-05 tab:
Column C        Column D
2627-503        Value to be returned

PF Outstandings Tab:
Column C        Column D
2627-503        PF-05-03
```

Comment: Please add your current code sample

Comment: Try sorting your lookup values, and specifying `True` for the last parameter... should be noticeably faster ([article (French)](https://www.excel-exercice.com/accelerer-la-fonction-recherchev/)). Beyond that... I think we really need to see more of what you're doing.

Comment: What is the exact formula you're using?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA:

If you can sort your Lookup table then you can use the Double VLOOKUP trick which is lightning fast.
This involves using a formula like this: in 'FISV 02-5'!$D2

```
=IF(VLOOKUP('FISV 03-05'!$C2,'PF Outstandings'!$C:$C,1,true)=FISV 03-05'!$C2, VLOOKUP('FISV 03-05'!$C2,'PF Outstandings'!$C:$D,2,true),"Not Found")
```

For more details see my blog post 
https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/vlookup-tricks-why-2-vlookups-are-better-than-1-vlookup/

Answer (score 1):

this may be fast:

```
Sub fastVlookup()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim lookUpDict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set lookUpDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim lookUpData As Variant
    Dim sourceData As Variant

    With Worksheets("FISV 03-05")
        sourceData = .Range("D1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)).value
    End With

    With Worksheets("PF Outstandings")
        lookUpData = .Range("D1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)).value
    End With

    With lookUpDict
        For i = 1 To UBound(lookUpData)
            .Add lookUpData(i, 1), lookUpData(i, 2)
        Next

        For i = 1 To UBound(sourceData)
            sourceData(i, 2) = .Item(sourceData(i, 1))
        Next
    End With

    Worksheets("FISV 03-05").Range("C1:D1").Resize(UBound(sourceData)).value = sourceData
End Sub
```

it requires adding "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" library reference to your project (while in VBA IDE, click Tools->References, scroll the listbox down to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" item, check mark it and click OK)

Comment: I get an error on the following line: .Add lookupdata(i,1),lookupdata(i,2) and it says "This key is already associated with an element of this collection"

Comment: then your lookup data column C has not unique values. is that allowed?

Comment: @ZacharyDesgain, any feedback?